# Word frequency list from contemporary young adult fiction?

Tags: resources

I'm looking for a resource that has frequent words found in young adult fiction.

Something like: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists/Contemporary_fiction_in_60_categories#Consumption

Comment: Interesting question. Might the open data stack exchange folks have a little more insight in to this question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a resource request.

Comment: I'm looking for a resource on "word choice and usage" in YA fiction. This is explicitly stated as an appropriate topic. I can't find where it says 'resource requests' are off-topic, but if that's true, I'd think it probably means asking questions like, "Can someone send me the .pdf of strunk & white's?"

Answer (score 0):

Google this "Trends and issues most seen in young adult literature". It should be the first result. If not the URL is "highered.mheducation.com/sites/dl/free/.../664244/Sample_chapter.pdf"  but don't type that in directly it will come up with a 404 error.

this might help:[image]

GOOD LUCK! I hope this helps.

Comment: This is a great resource, especially the listing of books! I didn't see anything about a word frequency list though.